# MongoDB get a partial document

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, express

I have a document stored in MongoDB:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "op": "someone",
   "title": "some title",
   "category": 1,
   "conversation": {
      "1": {
         "user": 2,
         "comment": "some comment"
      },
      "2": {
         "user": 9,
         "comment": "comment 2"
      },
      ......
      "26": {
         "user": 5,
         "comment": "comment 26"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to get this on request:
(e.g. POST {"id":1, "page":2})

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "op": "someone",
  "title": "some title",
  "category": 1,
  "conversation": {
     "11": {
        "user": 10,
        "comment": "comment 11"
     },
     ......
     "20": {
        "user": 25,
        "comment": "comment 25"
     }
   }
}
```

i.e. 10 comments starting on 11, that is

page 1: return comments 1 - 10,

page 2: return comments 11 - 20,

......

page 10: return comments 91 - 100

I am using NodeJS. Since processing this in node can use up a lot of memory. I would like to do this in Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make that process on MongoDB side, you can use skip() and limit() function

```
const document_by_page = 10;
const page = 1;

db.collection.find().skip(page * document_by_page).limit(document_by_page);
```

---

With the new information from your comments, you should use mongo db pipeline to process information on MongoDB side. Take a look at
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#mongodb-expression-exp.-filter.

Have a great day finding your solution

Comment: The problem is the whole json is a document.

Comment: Well this is not an issue, you currently do not need to access the document to skip and limit a set of document to paginate your set. I get your issue you want to paginate your conversation property that it ?

Comment: Yes. But this doesn't work since they are not separate documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Mongo aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to do some powerful reshaping of documents.

It looks like the [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-redact) stage would do what you want - there's a very similar [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#examples) on the MongoDB site where they want to retrieve specific elements from arrays within documents.